# circle.exe Stopped working while using graphics.h in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

I am using Code::Blocks 16.01 for coding in C++ every code runs properly without showing any problem or error.  But ever I runs a graphics program it shows a pop-up window with message circle.exe has stopped working(circle.cpp is the name of my program)(had already copied graphics.h ,winbigim.h and libbgi.a and also corrected the line 302 error in graphics.h and had also had done the linking work).

code that i am using is:-

```
//circle.cpp 
#include <graphics.h>

int main()
{
 int gd=DETECT,gm;
 initgraph(&gd,&gm," ");
 circle(100,100,50);
 getch();
 closegraph();
 return 0;
}
```

it shows a pop-up window with message **circle.exe has stopped working**.

But when ever I run the same  code in Turbo C++ it runs without any problem/error.

What should I do?

Comment: Both Turbo C++ and the "graphics" library are old remnants of old DOS. There's really no support for either on modern Windows systems. Try using some DOS emulator? Or learn modern C++ using a modern [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)?

Comment: Which BGI implementation are you using, [`SDL_bgi`](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is because the BGI graphics expect powers that modern systems don't give out willy-nilly anymore.

To use the old  library, your options are:

(1) Run your program in DosBox, and x86 emulator
[Dos Box](http://www.dosbox.com/)

The other option are to get a modern graphics library, like SDL(It's better way and I suggest you).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will start using  SDL from now.